# Setup c++ debugging on vscode (wsl ubuntu)

Tags: c++, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, debugging, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've been trying for hours and can't figure out how to set it up, even after following countless tutorials. I'm working on a multiple file project (both .cpp and .hpp if that changes anything) and really need to debug it. All I managed to do was put vscode in the debugging mode (the popup on the top showing the play, reset etc. buttons) but nothing is shown in the variables section and it doesn't show which line the debugger is on (also breakpoints don't work).

I compile the code using clang++ into main.exe. Can anyone please help?

This is my launch.json:

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "clang++ - Build and debug active file",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
        "args": ["user.cpp", "store.cpp", "product.cpp"],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: clang++ build active file",
    }
]
}
```

And this is my tasks.json

```
{
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: clang++ build active file",
        "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
        "args": [
            "-fcolor-diagnostics",
            "-fansi-escape-codes",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
    }
],
"version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Comment: The first thing you need to do is post your VSCode configuration files. If you can't debug then something is wrong with your set up, but it's hard to guess what that might be without seeing your set up. Please post any files as **text** not images.

Comment: Did you follow the official tutorial: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-wsl](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-wsl)

Comment: Your tasks.json is wrong for building an executable with more than 1 source file. The documentation explains that here and shows the change you need to make: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-wsl#_modifying-tasksjson](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-wsl#_modifying-tasksjson)

Comment: @drescherjm thanks, it helped, but I have one more problem - in the variables section all strings are called <incomplete type> and their value is hidden. The compiler recognises they're strings and uses them accordingly, it's just the debugger that's sketchy. Is there any workaround to that?